# how to call function after timeout function is done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I have a function with a timer, I want to call another function when the timer of the another function is done, so the first function will show a modal for 3 seconds, and the another funciton will show another modal, here is my code:

```
var fn = setTimeout(function(){
    $('#responseModal').modal('hide');
    return true;
}, 3000);

if(fn)

    $('#requestModal').modal('show');
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wouldn't

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#responseModal').modal('hide');
    $('#requestModal').modal('show');
}, 3000);
```

do the trick?

No need to return anything in the callback function for `setTimeout`. It's meaningless.